# Is there any editor which supports html and jQuery code completion?

Tags: jquery, html, editor

First of all, i use eclipse to edit my html files <strike>that's not weird at all</strike>. There are plugins for eclipse which supports html and jquery code completion. But eclipse takes too much memory of my system, and i want to get rid of eclipse for html editing.
Now is there any free editor which supports html and jQuery code completion.
No aptana please i don't like that.

Comment: I would recommend NetBeans, although you will probably run into similar memory issues since it is also a (large) Java-based IDE.

Comment: @justin: yes netBeans is other option but with similar problem

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 [support intellisense for jQuery when you add a VSDOC file for it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx). I believe the [free Express versions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) also support this, though can't confirm this from personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

I you are using windows, you can use the express version of visual studio web platform - [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/). It is free and has good HTML support with javascript and jQuery intellisense.

It should work fine under mono, if you are using Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Personal I'm using Netbeans wich support your requirements and it has a little bit better performance. But I guess you don't want a full IDE. So i recommend Notepad++. I've heared that there is a plugin for jQuery.

Also see: [What is your favourite JavaScript/jQuery code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713889/what-is-your-favourite-javascript-jquery-code-editor)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following...

- Eclipse - had the same problem as you
- Aptana - had the same problem as you
- NetBeans - pretty much the same problem
- Web Storm - pretty much the same problem
- Visual Studio - pretty much the same problem

Of course, this just means that if you want your IDE to compile in the background and provide intellisense, it is going to eat some memory, so you kind of have to live with that, or use something that doesn't give you code-completion (Notepad++) or does it in a more noddy-way without background-compilation.